# Do these two vector initializations accomplish the same result?

Tags: c++

Are these effectively doing the same thing?

```
vector<MyType> stuff;
MyClass(MyType *things, int numThings){
    for (int i = 0; i < numThings; ++i){
        //stuff[i] = things[i]; //original version of question, fixed
         stuff.push_back(things[i]);
    }
}
```

vs.

```
vector<MyType> stuff;
MyClass(MyType *things, int numThings) : stuff(things, things+numThings) {}//fixed
```

If they are, any more or less overhead using either approach? (except for the additional typing in method 1)

Comment: One compiles, the other doesn't?

Comment: By `stuff[i] = things[i]`, do you mean `stuff.push_back(things[i])`?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted this: `: stuff(things, things + numThings) {}`

Comment: Have you tried both approaches before posting the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The first method crashes, since it accesses elements beyond the end of the zero-size vector.  If this bug is fixed by resizing the vector first, elements in the vector will first be initialized, and then be overwritten using `operator=`.  If instead the bug is fixed by using `push_back()` in the loop, then vector may be resized during the loop.

The second method initializes the vector with the desired contents in one step, it is to be preferred since this is simpler and obviously correct.  It also does not have the overhead of resizing the vector, and does not have the overhead of initializing elements twice.

**Edit:** Looks like the second one is also a bug:

```
stuff(things, numThings)
```

should be

```
stuff(things, things + numThings)
```

I can never remember all of the constructors for standard library classes, funny how `string` has this constructor but `vector` doesn't.

### Fixed versions

The following two versions are roughly equivalent:

```
MyClass(MyType *things, int numThings)
{
    stuff.reserve(numThings);
    for (int i = 0; i < numThings; i++)
        stuff.push_back(things[i]);
}

MyClass(MyType *things, int numThings)
    : stuff(things, things + numThings);
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes see `+1` added like such, it this necessary? `stuff(things, numThings+1)`

Comment: Looks like adding something to the "length" is good practice anyway, according to the other answer

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: No, that's not "adding something to the length", that's something else — pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

This would probably be the best:

```
MyClass(MyType*things, int numThings) : stuff(things, things + numThings) {}
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by the same result. Assuming both methods actually worked (you need to modify the second one to match Dietrich's and others' suggestions), you still have one way which uses an initializer list and another where the vector is filled in the body of the constructor.

The second one will result in a vector whose contents are valid *at the start of the constructor body*.

Though both approaches will end with a vector of the same size and contents, the second approach is preferable, because:

1. It is cleaner
2. It is also probably faster.